# How to publish an artifact to a remote repository using gradle

Tags: gradle

I wanted to publish an artifact to a remote repository identified by a url . Here is my build.gradle file. This is a java gradle project with some dependencies. I was able to publish this to a local .m2 repository and make use of this in another project.

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.mob.ci'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven{url 'https://proget1..../maven2/Maven/'}
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://proget1..../maven2/Maven/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  your build.gradle seems good. 

May be your repos url (https://proget1..../maven2/Maven) is not well configured ? 
is it secured ?

Comment: Thank you. I need to pass in the username and password to access the repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the update the build.gradle file, that resolved the issue. Thank you @soung for the tip. I need to specify the credentials for accessing the repository.

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.mob.ci'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'maven'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    maven{url 'https://proget1..../maven2/Maven/'}
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://proget1..../maven2/Maven/'
            credentials {
                username = deployRepoUsername
                password = deployRepoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```